# Message not sent/received unless a page will be reload in Rocketchat

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, chat, rocket.chat

We’ve cloned the latest rocket chat repo from git and introduced some custom APIs to meet our client’s requirements. The update chat (having custom APIs) is working fine on local. But after deploying the app to Heroku, we’re facing this issue. The issue is, when user A sends a message to user B, B doesn’t receive it and A has this message with grey text. If the user B reloads his chat, he receives the message. After this, if user A now reloads the page, he gets the message with standard black color text.
The issue is just with Heroku deployed app. While the same codebase running on local machine is working fine.
Any type of help would highly be appreciated…!

Comment: `While the same codebase running on local machine is working fine` indicates that there are some issues with the deployment. Please add (anonymized) information to your question on how you actually deploy (configs, scripts etc.)

Comment: How did you wait after sending the message? In deployment, if you didn't set up oplog tailing yet, the database is only polled every 10 seconds for new results for reactive queries.

Comment: @Jankapunkt yes on deployment I was facing some issues, that is why I added BYPASS_OPLOG_VALIDATION = true in the configuration, if I removed this server was unable to start.

Comment: @ChristianFritz how can I set up ReplicaSet OpLog? I did not find any solution of this, that is why i added BYPASS_OPLOG_VALIDATION = true in an environment , then my server was started but now i am facing this issue on Heroku, but my local setup is working fine

Comment: Please see my first question. It's important to know the answer to that to tell whether your issue is related to oplog or not. It's fine to run without oplog tailing, it's just less efficient and less reactive.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I waited more than 2 mins, but I can hear the sound of a new message on another account but the message just showed after refresh. and on my side message is just gray until I refreshed.

Comment: ok, then it's not related to the missing oplog tailing. Next I would verify that the websockets are still open and DDP is still operational. I would do that using the Meteor dev tools extension in Chrome. When you open that, you can see the messages that are sent and received. Also, please post the publication code here.

Comment: @XquicDevs did you find any issue about this problem

Comment: No, I am using aws now